# Need to return the datepicker dialog value in android

Tags: android

I need to return the selected value in datepicker dialog, check it out my following coding,

this is my adapter class where i have used datepicker dialog

```
if (holder.mClientNextvisit.isChecked() == true) {
    holder.SelectDateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    holder.mClientSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            Log.d("Selected date", "---->" + day);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DateListener(), year, month, day);
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

}
```

**This is my datesetlistener class**

```
class DateListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int mYear = year;
    int mMonth = monthOfYear;
    int mDay = dayOfMonth;
    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
            .append("/").append(mDay).append("/").append(mYear)
            .append(" ");

    Log.d("date", "---->" + date);

}
```

Now i need to return the selected date in adapter class, please help me.

Comment: You can store date in static String or sharedpreference then use anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using anonymous class ?

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,
    new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
            int mYear = year;
            int mMonth = monthOfYear;
            int mDay = dayOfMonth;
            StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder()
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mDay)
                .append("/").append(mYear).append(" ");

            Log.d("date", "---->" + date);

        }
    }, year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mHolder` as a `TextView` pass a reference to your listener and directly use it.

```
class DateListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
  private TextView mHolder;
  public DateListener(TextView mHolder) { this.mHolder = mHolder; }
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int mYear = year;
    int mMonth = monthOfYear;
    int mDay = dayOfMonth;
    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
            .append("/").append(mDay).append("/").append(mYear)
            .append(" ");

    Log.d("date", "---->" + date);
    mHolder.setText(date);
}

DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
context, new DateListener(mHolder), year,month, day);
dialog.show();
```